# Why "OnActionExecuted" execute in reverse order?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 action filters "ActionFilter1" & "ActionFilter2,

```
public class ActionFilter1 : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Application["Order"] += "Action 1: OnActionExecuting <br/>";
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Application["Order"] += "Action 1: OnActionExecuted <br/>";
    }
}

public class ActionFilter2 : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Application["Order"] += "Action 2: OnActionExecuting <br/>";
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Application["Order"] += "Action 2: OnActionExecuted <br/>";
    }
}
```

I applied both filters on an controller action method with "Order",

```
[ActionFilter1(Order = 1)]
    [ActionFilter2(Order = 2)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

While Page is executed on browser, I got below output of action filters executing,

Action 1: OnActionExecuting

Action 2: OnActionExecuting

Action 2: OnActionExecuted

Action 1: OnActionExecuted

**Question** - Why "OnActionExecuted" execute in reverse order, while "OnActionExecuting" order is correct as I supplied in attribute?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented behavior. Here is the link [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx):

> The OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext),
>   OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext), and
>   OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext) filters run in forward order.
>   The OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext),
>   OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext), and
>   OnException(ExceptionContext) filters run in reverse order.